# Using equals() after serialization

Tags: java, serialization, equals

I have the following method to convert a file (containing a serialized object) back into an object:

```
public static <T, C extends Class<T>> T readSerializableObjectFromFile(final Path path, final C clazz) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(path, "path");
    Objects.requireNonNull(clazz, "clazz");
    try (ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(Files.newInputStream(path))) {
        return clazz.cast(objectInputStream.readObject());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Say I have an object of type `Organization`, which has `equals` and `hashCode` methods, written in a file, what happens when I call the following?

```
Organization organization = 
    readSerializableObjectFromFile(myFile, Organization.class);
```

Does `organization.hashCode()` use the `Object#hashCode` or `Organization#hashCode` implementation?

And does the behaviour change when I store a `List<Organization>` in the file, and then retrieve it via

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Organization> organizations =
    readSerializableObjectFromFile(myFile, List.class)
```

Comment: `...which has equals and hashCode methods, written in a file...` what do you mean by that

Comment: @PhilippSander That I have an object of class `Organization` having equals and hashCode methods, and that object has been written to a file.

Comment: ah ok... i thought you meant the methods are written in a file. that's why i was confused.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, `equals` and `hashCode` are just mere methods, nothing special about them. Serialisation is only involves fields, never methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of dynamic dispatch, whenever you invoke a method like `hashCode()` or any other method, the particular function that is called depends on the *runtime type* of the object (not the declared type of the object). The ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream will preserve the runtime type of objects (the runtime class is written on serialization and is thus used to instantiate the object on deserialization).

Your cast operation just checks that the result is of the correct type (it isn't the reason that the deserialized data is of that type), and it isn't causing the data to be converted or truncated (if that was what you were worried or concerned was happening here).

As for List<T>, the hash method is not tied to a particular type argument. The fact that the type was erased (which is how the structure is internally represented, anyway) does not change the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> Say I have an object of type `Organization`, which has `equals` and `hashCode` methods, written in a file, what happens when I call the following?

When you call your `readSerializableObjectFromFile` method, one or more new objects are created, based on the state in the file.  The fact that you have overridden hashcode and equals doesn't alter that fact.

> Does `organization.hashCode()` use the `Object#hashCode` or `Organization#hashCode` implementation?

The version of `hashCode()` used is determined exactly the same way, whether or not it is the original object or a copy produced by serialization / deserialization.

> And does the behaviour change when I store a `List<Organization>` in the file, and then retrieve it

No, it doesn't.

---

These questions are a bit strange ...

... but maybe what you are missing is that when you serialize and the deserialize an object using Java object streams, what you get is *copies* of the original object, and its closure.  You don't get the same instances back ...

If your classes implement `equals` and `hashCode` to have "identity-based" equality semantics, then the copied objects are different objects and hence not be equal.  But if your `equals` and `hashCode` to have "value-based" equality semantics, the copied objects should have the same "value" ...

Comment: The latter might in error here, I'm doing some additional testing and might come back then, I am forwarding the serialization in `Organization` to an `EnumMap`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how object was created (directly using constructor, deserialized or via clone). If class of this object defines `hashCode` (or `equals`) that method will be used.